# nginx rule to capture header and append value as query string

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-headers, querystring

I have an interesting problem I need to solve in nginx: one of the sites I'm building receives inbound traffic on port 80 (and only port 80) which may have a certain header set in the request. If this header is present I need to capture the value of it and append that as a querystring parameter before doing a temporary redirect (rewrite) to a different (secure) server, while passing the paramater and any other querystring params along. This should be very doable, but how!?

Many thanks,

JS

Answer (score 2):

```
return https://example.com$uri?my_header=$http_my_header&$args;
```

If I understand you correctly.

- http://nginx.org/r/return
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables